# Spacing problem between equation and surrounding text

Tags: spacing, equations

I want to insert formula in text and I used `equation` as shown:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

So, $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ is representation if and only if

\begin{equation*}
\forall g,h \in G) \hspace{2mm} \rho(gh)=\rho(g)\rho(h).
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

My problem is too big vertical spacing before and after formula.

Comment: remove the blank line between the text and the equation.  that will always leave too much space.

Comment: By the way, I would use `\colon` instead of `:`; `\to` instead of `\rightarrow`; `\quad` instead of `\hspace{2mm}`.

Comment: Why is `\colon` preferable to `:`?

Comment: You can also modify the parameters \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip if you really want to modify the default spacing (after applying Barbara's suggestion).

Comment: @AnnieCarter When you're talking about functions, you want the colon to be closer to the function name as opposed to equidistant between name and the domain–range portion. A plain `:` is (I believe) more useful in set comprehensions: `\{ x : x = 0 \pmod 3 \}`.

Comment: Barbara, I am new in TeX so every comment is welcome. :-) I changed : to \colon, 'rightarrow to \to and \hspace{2mm} to \quad. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\useshortskip` from the `nccmath` package — but will change only `\abovedisplayskip` – or a `center`environment — the difference is very small – or create a `myequ` environment, that adds `smallskip` to `\baselineskip` (this may be changed, of course).

Here is a code that shows these different possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newenvironment{myequ}{%
\smallskip\par\centering$\displaystyle}
{$\smallskip\par}

\begin{document}

\noindent With the \verb+equation*+ environment : \medskip

So, $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ is representation if and only if
\begin{equation*}
\forall g,h \in G \hspace{2mm} \rho(gh)=\rho(g)\rho(h).
\end{equation*}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. \\

\noindent With a \verb+center + environment : \medskip

So, $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ is representation if and only if
\begin{center}
$\displaystyle
 \forall g,h \in G \hspace{2mm} \rho(gh)=\rho(g)\rho(h). $
\end{center}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. \\

\noindent With \verb+\useshortskip+ : \medskip

So, $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ is representation if and only if\useshortskip
\begin{equation*}
\forall g,h \in G \hspace{2mm} \rho(gh)=\rho(g)\rho(h).
\end{equation*}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. \\

\noindent With the \verb+myequ+ environment : \medskip

So, $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ is representation if and only if\useshortskip
\begin{myequ}
\forall g,h \in G \hspace{2mm} \rho(gh)=\rho(g)\rho(h).
\end{myequ}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. \\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Myequ" solved problem completely. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bernard: In order to use the `myequ` environment, what package should be installed ?

Comment: @DavidC.: none, it uses basic LaTeX. Note that such environments cannot be referenced:  they use no counter.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly believe that the default values of the length parameters `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` make LaTeX insert a bit too much vertical whitespace above and below a displayed equation, you could reduce those values a bit. E.g.,

```
\addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-1ex}
\addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-1ex}
```

Don't go overboard, though.

Do also follow barbara beeton's advice not to leave blank lines above and below the code that defines the displayed equations. And, if your document loads the `setspace` package and uses a spacing setting *other than* `\singlespacing`, do load the package with the option `nodisplayskipstretch`. Doing so turns off line stretching before and after displays. If your document uses `\doublespacing` you'll notice a huge effect.

Comment: @MicoIn the preamble, I have written `\addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-1ex}
\addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-1ex}` but no effect in the space between text and equation, and no effect between the equation and next text. I have `\usepackage{setspace}` What could be happening ?

Comment: @DavidC. - "No effect" is not a very specific diagnosis. To have a chance to find out what may be going on, please consider posting a new question with a full MWE that establishes the problem you're looking to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Barbara's comment about removing the blank line, you can manually set line spacing using the `spacing` environment from the `setspace` package (see [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Line_spacing)! from the LaTeX wikibook).

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{0.2}
So, $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ is representation if and only if
\begin{equation*}
    \forall g,h \in G) \hspace{2mm} \rho(gh)=\rho(g)\rho(h).
\end{equation*} 
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```